# When should I put a `requires` clause in a template function's signature instead of before it?

Tags: c++, overloading, c++-concepts, overload-resolution, requires-clause

In C++20 you can add a `requires` clause (1) after a template parameter list as well as (2) after a function declaration (like a specifier). In the following snippet `foo` is an example of (1) and `bar` is an example of (2).

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
  requires std::is_integral_v<T>
bool foo(T x) {
  return x > 0;
}

template <typename T>
bool foo(T x) {
  return false;
}

template <typename T>
bool bar(T x)
  requires std::is_integral_v<T>
{
  return x > 0;
}

template <typename T>
bool bar(T x) {
  return false;
}
```

How is overload resolution going to differ between functions like `foo` and functions like `bar`? Is there any difference?

Comment: With multiple constraints the order in which they're evaluated changes depending on where the constraints are placed lexically, but there's no difference in the simple example you have here.

Comment: No difference. I would put restrictions on the template parameters right after they are declared, and restrictions on the function parameters right after *they* are declared. You might have both!